# Python throw UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python

I am using python 2.6, and from what I read, reading a binary file will result in string, but I am unable to concatenante the string with a B"\r\n" string. I have searched but most result are concatenating UTF string while my case is concatenating binary with string

Below codes work fine until the line body = "\r\n".join(lines), supposely lines are list that has both normal ASCII string and also Binary content read from file, when joining them together throws UnicodeDecodeError, how do I join a binary data with a string? below code is for uploading a file to web.

```
        def get_content_type (filename):
            return mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0] or 'application/octet-stream'

        def encode_field (field_name):
            return ('--' + boundary,
                    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % field_name,
                    '', str (data [field_name]))

        def encode_file (field_name):
            filename = files[field_name]
            return ('--' + boundary,
                    'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (field_name, StringOps.GetFilename(filename)),
                    'Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename),
                    '', open(filename, 'rb').read())

        lines = []
        if (data):
            for name in data:
               lines.extend(encode_field(name))

        for name in files:
            lines.extend(encode_file(name))

        lines.extend(('--%s--' % boundary, ''))
        #BELOW THROWS EXCEPTION
        body = "\r\n".join(lines)
        #UnicodeDecodeError, something like that
        print "Baa"
```

Below some sample I made up

```
data = []
data.append(open("1.mkv", 'rb').read())
data.append("somestring")

body = "\r\n".join(data)
#throws exception
```

Comment: Please try to provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions). Particularly include the input data that causes the problem, and the (full) traceback.

Comment: My point was for you to post **less** code, not **more**. Reduce the issue to a simple test case that contains someting like `body = "\r\n".join(lines)`, and that anyone can copy and paste into a file and run, and get the same error you got.

Comment: Does `'\r\n'.join(unicode(line) for line in lines)` help you?

Comment: hi Lukas, I modified, please help. Hi Steinar, I am not allowed to use unicode(line) since line is binary file, changing to unicode will break the file since the body is going to be written to a file stream and must be able to reopen again

Comment: @LukasGraf I'm gonna start quoting that one two.